# reason: Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i have this code inside of a middlewere function:

```
const newPassword = req.body.password;
const userId = req.body.userId;
const token = req.body.passwordToken;
let resetUser;
User.findOne({
    _id: userId,
    ResetToken: token,
    ResetTokenExpiration: {$gt: Date.now()}
 })
```

and i get this error:

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "629f6d03246e5c32643f4f06 " (type string) at path "_id" for model "User"
reason: Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
```

Comment: There is an unwanted space at the end of your `userId`.

Comment: so what can i do about it?

Comment: It comes from `req.body.userId`, so the extra space might have been typed in an HTML form. Or where does it come from?